# How to add more than one Objects of same type with same Key inside a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, iteration

Hi I think this is very simple problem but I am not able to get through it right now;
There are two kinds of Objects-`RuleObject,TaskObject`
Following are definitions of `RuleObject,TaskObject`

```
RuleObject
  ruleID,RulePatternType,RulePrint

TaskObject
  taskID,taskName,Org,ruleID
```

`ruleArrayList` is all objects of `RuleObjects`

`taskArrayList` is all objects of `TaskObjects`

The final formation will be to fetch all `RuleObjects` used by `TaskObjects` and arrange by `RuleObjects` 
like example shown below:

---

```
RuleObject.RulePatternType1

 TaskName1  TaskOrg1    RUleObject.rulePrint1
 TaskName2  TaskOrg2    RuleObject.rulePrint1
```

---

```
RuleObject.RulePatternType2

 TaskName3  TaskOrg1    RUleObject.rulePrint2
 TaskName4  TaskOrg2    RuleObject.rulePrint2
 TaskName5  TaskOrg3    RUleObject.rulePrint2
 TaskName6  TaskOrg4    RuleObject.rulePrint2
```

---

**Code snippet:**

```
List<TaskObject> taskArrayList = compModIF.getRecurringTasksForOrgsAndEffDate(allOrgIds, effDate);        
        List<RuleObject> ruleArrayList = compModIF.getComplianceTaskRecurrenceRules();
        Map ruleTypes = new HashMap();
        Map groupTaskTypes = new HashMap();
        Map groupRecurRulesNames = new HashMap();
        Map masterMapOfallMaps = new HashMap();
        Map recurPrintMap = new HashMap();
        Map recurPatternTypeMap = new HashMap();
        List groupRecuringTaskTypesList = null;
        Map filterRules = new HashMap();
        List completedList = new ArrayList();
        for(Iterator iter = ruleArrayList .iterator(); iter.hasNext();)
        {
            RuleObject ruleBase = (RuleObject)iter.next();              
            ruleTypes.put(ruleBase.getRecurRuleID(),ruleBase);

        }

        if (recurringTaskList != null)
        {
            for (Iterator it = taskArrayList .iterator(); it.hasNext();)
            {               
                TaskObject aTaskDef = (TaskObject)it.next();
                groupRecuringTaskTypesList = new ArrayList();
                if(ruleTypes.containsKey(aTaskDef.getTaskRecurRuleIDAsLong()))
                {
                    RuleObject ruleBase = (RuleObject)ruleTypes.get(aTaskDef.getTaskRecurRuleIDAsLong());                   
                    groupRecuringTaskTypesList.add(aTaskDef);                   
                    groupTaskTypes.put(ruleBase.getRecurRuleID(),groupRecuringTaskTypesList);
                    groupRecurRulesNames.put(ruleBase.getRecurRuleID(), ruleBase.getRecurRuleName());
                    if(ruleBase.getRecurPatternType()==ComplianceCodes.TASK_RECUR_PATTERN_TYPE_DAILY)
                    {
                        completedList= getDailyRecursCommentsAsCompleted(ruleBase.printRule());
                        recurPrintMap.put(ruleBase.getRecurRuleID(), completedList);
                    }
                    //groupRecuringTaskTypes = new ArrayList();
                    recurPatternTypeMap.put(ruleBase.getRecurRuleID(), ruleBase.getRecurPatternType());

                }
            }
       }
```

The problem here is for 1 ruleID there are multiple arraylists because of which I am able to get the last added list.
Can any one suggest better alternative for this.

Comment: Your code would be a lot clearer to start with if you would avoid using raw types for all your variables (ruleTypes etc).

Comment: You should use generic maps if at all possible. How about having a map whose key is a rule or rule id, and whose value is a List of List of tasks. In other words, a `List<List<TaskObject>>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't really follow your example too closely, but it sounds like what you need is a multimap - a mapping from a single key to multiple values.

[Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) provides an [interface](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v9.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) for this and various implementations, usually accessed via [`Multimaps`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v9.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html).

Comment: wow!Is this free to use ?any licences information will be helpful

Comment: @GustlyWind: From the first linked page: "Code license: Apache License 2.0".

Answer (score 2):

You have to store a Collection for each key:

```
Map<KeyType, Collection<ValueType>> map = 
                       new HashMap<KeyType, Collection<ValueType>>()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attain it simply by using Object as the value. and define the Map as shown below.

`Map map = new HashMap()`

Then when u set an ordinary object **without multiple value**
set for the key and value as any valueObject
`map.put("key", valueObject)`

when you want to add more than one, you can check for exiting key `map.containsKey("key")` and then add it to an arraylist and add remaining values into this list `map.put("key", valueObjectList)`.

*Note*: just make sure that when u retrive it next time, do a `instanceof` check before you access the value as an object or list.
*Alternate soln*: store value as a list of object. it is simpler to code.